# Table, vertical separation line for the second column is too short

Tags: tables

I have a problem with the vertical lines, the second vertical line doesn't fill the cell completely as the first one, the obtained output is this:
 [image]

Here the complete snippet tested with Sharelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{ciao}
  \label{tab:solutions}
  \center
  \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
      \toprule
      Task & primo & secondo \\
      \midrule 
      Twitter \\ anonymization & okokokokoko &  okokokoko \\
      \midrule 
      IP partial \\ anonymization & ahiahiahaihaihaihai & okioki \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The second line should fill the cell as the first, how do I do it?

Regards

Comment: The user guide of the `booktabs` package is very clear: If you want to use the macros of the `booktabs` package, *don't use any vertical rules*. Conversely, if you want to employ vertical rules anyway, *don't employ the macros of the `booktabs` package*. Assuming you don't really have to typeset stuff like "okokokokoko" -- in which case there's probably no scope for help anyway :-) -- I suggest replacing `\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}` and recompiling.

Comment: Also, if you insist on maintaining vertical rules, consider replacing `Twitter` with `Twitter &&` and replacing`IP partial` with`IP partial &&`.

Comment: Mico great! It works, if you create an answer from your last comment I'll elect it as good answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get complete vertical rules between the second and third columns, I suggest replacing

```
      Twitter \\ anonymization & okokokokoko &  okokokoko \\
      \midrule 
      IP partial \\ anonymization & ahiahiahaihaihaihai & okioki \\
```

with

```
      Twitter && \\ anonymization & okokokokoko &  okokokoko \\
      \midrule 
      IP partial && \\ anonymization & ahiahiahaihaihaihai & okioki \\
```

More generally, though, you should reconsider the case for using vertical rules in the first place. Does your table really need it or does it actually look better *without* any vertical rules?

Moreover, the user guide of the `booktabs` package is very clear:

- If you want to use the macros of the `booktabs` package, don't use any vertical rules. No exceptions.
- Conversely, if you want to employ vertical rules anyway, don't employ the macros of the `booktabs` package.

I would therefore like to suggest that you replace `\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}` and then recompile the document. I'm quite confident that you'll prefer the result, which is a much more "open" look.

Comment: I'm currently forced to use the vertical lines, not my choice :-), but your suggestion (&&) works like a charm.